# How to compile a text are VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-extensions

I have created a TextMate syntax highlighter extension for VS Code but am unsure how to compile it to the VIX format which VS Code can install. Right now I can use the extension running a debug command that creates a second VS Code window with the extension installed.

I couldn’t find any information on the Microsoft documentation about compiling TextMate grammar extensions.

I am using a template I found online at https://github.com/gctse/syntax-highlighting-VS-Code-example. I have only modified the language configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *compilation* step. The `.vsix` file is the *bundled extension*, created by `vsce`.

Follow the [Publishing Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension) instructions, and you are good to go.

Hope this helps